# How to add same javascript to mutually-exclusive checkboxes in Acrobat pdf?

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I have 2 mutually-exclusive checkboxes in an Acrobat X pdf form. Checking either box needs to hide a set of text fields. I've assigned the same javascript to both checkboxes, but the fields only hide if the 1st box is checked. Nothing happens when the 2nd box is checked. Any ideas? here's the script I've used (not knowing anything about javascript!):

```
var showHide = event.target.isBoxChecked(0) ? display.hidden : display.visible;

this.getField("Joint Address 1").display         = showHide;
this.getField("Joint City 1").display            = showHide;
this.getField("Joint State 1").display           = showHide;
this.getField("Joint Zip/Postal Code 1").display = showHide;
this.getField("Joint Country 1").display         = showHide;
```

Comment: The documentation seems to suggest that the parameter in the isBoxChecked call is an index used when you have multiple checkboxes with the same name. Have you tried changing the "0" to "1" in the second checkbox? Also, you're probably going to want a condition that tests both checkboxes, so if the previous assumption is correct you'll likely want something like "event.target.isBoxChecked(0) || event.target.isBoxChecked(1)" as you mentioned that whatever box is checked, you want the edit fields to be hidden.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the 0 to 1 did work. I had a feeling it would be something simple that I just missed.

Comment: I'll rephrase my comment as an answer - if you could approve that the topic can be 'closed' so others know what the solution is

Answer (score 1):

The Acrobat documentation indicates that the parameter to "isBoxChecked" is in fact the index to the check box you want to address *if* there are multiple check boxes with the same name.

This means changing "0" to "1" as parameter value lets you address the other check box and solves the problem